# Event handler binded to class created after DOM loads not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a jQuery function that adds a row to a table for each search result returned from an API. Each row includes a link button, which is given the class 'js-run-apn-button.'

When the link is clicked, it's supposed to fire the function apnData, but it fails to trigger. I'm pretty sure this is because the link class is added after the dom is first loaded so the event fails to bind. I can fix this specific issue by adding in the event handler inside the function that creates the new class rather than in the $document.ready() function, but that complicates the program. So I'm wondering if there's another way around this, and more broadly, what is the best way to deal with this issue in general.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-run-apn-button').on('click', apnData);
    ...
}

function multipleResults(response) {
    $('.result-table > tbody').append('<tr><td><a class="button blueButton js-run-apn-button" href="#">Search APN</a></td></tr>');
    ...
}
```

Comment: `live('click', function() {...` (is deprecated, but is sweet) will work

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

You have to handle event delegation properly for dynamically generated elements. You have to use the syntax as below.

```
$('document').on('click','.js-run-apn-button', apnData);
```

Note: Don't use `document` for performance issues. Use the nearest parent which is static and always present in DOM instead.

For 1.7 and older jquery versions, use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Syntax below.

```
$(".js-run-apn-button").live("click", apnData);
```

This is deprecated in 1.7 & removed in 1.9

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.on` function or `.live` function (.live if you use older jquery version < 1.7).

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-run-apn-button', function(event){

or

$(".js-run-apn-button").live("click", function(event){
```